# Why php artisan serve works and http://localhost/etc = error 500

Tags: laravel

This is my question and I dont know what to add to have the 30 characers required to be published so I write it and I thank you for answers

Comment: Hard to tell. No hints of any sorts in the error log? What server are you using?

Comment: Im on Linux Mint and I use Apache2 (LAMP).

Comment: About the error log ... anything there? Apache is set up correctly? `public` is DocumentRoot, `.htaccess` is allowed etc?

Answer (score 1):

Check if application is in development mode, and send the message of exception. Unfortunately, we are not wizards. :-)

If you still have 500 without message, check app files permissions (especially storage logs), and make sure you have installed vendors.